# Call function in javascript file from typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a .js file in my Angular's assets folder with this format:

```
;(function($){ 
    $.someFunction() {...} 
})(jQuery)
```

**Question**: It possible to call functions from my .js file from a Typescript file?

Note: I'm avoiding to export javascript functions in a typescript file, I want to use it directly from the file.

Comment: that looks like a function you define on jquery, I'm guessing importing jquery in ts and calling the function on it should work.

Comment: After that file has been parsed and run, `someFunction` will be bound to the `jQuery` object. How about you just try it and see if it works? That would likely be faster than waiting for someone to answer...

Comment: You should make a `.d.ts` file.

Comment: It doesn't work, does not recogniza someFunction... @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: @RafaelReyes Are you positive that your JS code is running before you try to access the function in TS? Second, your syntax is incorrect. You should be doing `$.someFunction = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

As toskv said, that's jquery. In order to import it you'll need to do the following (assuming you have jquery installed):

Run this in the command line to install jquery types

```
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Add this to the file in which you wish to use the lib

```
import * as $ from ‘jquery’;
```

Comment: Hi, I just follow your comment and when I call $.someFunction() from my TypeScript class it displays "Error:(38, 12) TS2339: Property 'someFunction' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic<HTMLElement>'.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `$` is defined in your JavaScript code, then yes, but you will need to declare to the TypeScript compiler that that variable actually exists, which you can do by using the `declare` keyword:

```
declare const $: any;
```

(Though this doesn't give you proper typings, so you might want to fetch the jQuery declaration file, which you can find [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jquery))